# converting latitude and longitude in google map?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am creating an application in which by clicking a button on android mobile i can track the a gps tracker device. In response to the button clicked the gps device containing a sim card response with its latitude and longitude as well as the speed of device. The message sent by the device is received in my mobile's inbox. i want to convert that latitude and longitude into a google map or atleast in some address form.Can someone suggest me a proper way or give me some hint how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get current location coordinates and city name using below code

---

```
private class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {          
            if(location!=null){             
                locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
                String longitude = "Longitude: " +location.getLongitude();
                String latitude = "Latitude: " +location.getLatitude();
                String altitiude = "Altitiude: " + location.getAltitude();          
                String cityName;

                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                public List<Address> addresses= gcd.getFromLocation (double latitude1, double longitude1, int maxResults)   

                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                showLocation.setText("City Name: "+cityName+"+ "\n"+longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n" + altitiude);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

---

then you can get gmap using city name or location value using this code

---

```
public void getMap(String location) {
        map_location = "geo:0,0?q=" + location;
        Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(map_location);
        Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);            
    }
```

---

or even you can check [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html) example for little help

let me know if still you get trouble

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways which I think might be useful for you.

1. Use the GPS coordinates that you already have and open the maps intent and center the ap at those lat and long.
2. Use some third party api which will give you the nearby address for the latitude and longitude and use it in the way you want.

Note: Both of these will need internet permission also. The first one will also require you to have the maps api key but that is the easy solution among these two but both should be relatively easy.